# How to use custom fonts in alacritty without installing them

Tags: alacritty

Im trying to have portable Alacritty with custom font, is there any way i can use my custom font without installing it? For example, with the path of the .ttf file

It worked with the installed fonts, but when i try it with the path, it doesn't find it, i suppose this happens because it treats it like the name